# Macroeconometric models with wrong input but better fit/forecast

Tags: macroeconomics, econometrics

Could you give an example of the situation when if you input wrong (economic-wise, but not mathematically) parameters the model could fit/forecast better?

Comment: You are not asking about spurious regressions, are you?
http://www.tylervigen.com/spurious-correlations
They fit well but have 0 forecasting power. Do you mean things that are not "wrong" but unexpected? Like if male underwear sales rise it signals the end of an economic depression?

Comment: @denesp no. What I'm trying to find out is the possibility of for example we have Y=Model(X), and X is determined by some economics conditions which are not necessary for the Model to be solved/worked with. Then by disregarding those 'extra' economics conditions, and focusing only on the solely mathematical ones, we could find a better fit for the observed data Y.

Comment: I guess this has to depend on how you define better fit. (Like $R^2$ or adjusted $R^2$.) It seems to me you can never get a better model by throwing away information/data.

Comment: @denesp https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting